# failed to run tomcat in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I was doing a servlet project in eclipse.
when i tried to run my tomcat server in eclipse like this(right click server-start)
[run tomcat in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m5aC.png) 
(and neither can i run my servlet app on tomcat through eclipse)
it'll show "a java exception has occured"
[java exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAi2d.png)
and in the debugging window,it look like this
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa2N1.png)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/logging/Logger


at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:61)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:181)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:133)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.logging.Logger
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 6 more
```

the problem is ,the server was perfectly well in eclipse yesterday,and although i can't run tomcat in eclipse ,i can start tomcat outside eclipse.i tried a different version of tomcat,reinstall eclipse and tomcat,and searched online,but the problem was not solved

i installed jdbc for sqlserver and imported the sql-jar in one of the java project in eclipse ,and besides that,i cant think of anything that can possibly make this happen....

and before i tried to reinstall tomcat,there was another error in eclipse ,,`Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at \Servers\Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config`
and after i reinstalled tomcat,this was gone ,but tomcat still cant run

thank you for your time..btw

Comment: SUGGESTION: Try creating a brand new Eclipse workspace creating a "clean environment"), add your Tomcat server, and see if that works.  Q: Any idea "what changed" since it Tomcat/Eclipse worked for you yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was solved just after i posted this question.....
i tried to use a different completely new workspace for eclipse ,and it worked..
i have no idea why...

-----update---------------------------------------------

i found where the problem is,but still dont know why.
like i said above,i was trying to install jdbc and java-sql environment,within the steps,there was one step it requires to specify the exact loction where my jre folder is,(something like that)
and i was using jdk12, which dont have a jre folder in the jdk folder,and i found a way to generate the jre folder manually,and that was what i did.and the database part worked out pretty good.
(it seems the jdbc version i used is not the best,i suppose in the correct version it doesnt require a jre folder to be specified)

anyway,after i deleted the jre folder i generated manually, i re-configured the tomcat server in eclipse,and then the server can run in eclipse

Comment: Too bad I didn't give my suggestion as an "answer" (instead of a "comment") ;)  Glad you got it working. Something in your workspace metadata just got "corrupted". :(  Pleae "accept" your own answer when you get a chance. It'll help others who might experience the same problem.

Comment: @paulsm4 i found where went wrong(it was explained above) but still dont know why changing workspace could solve the problem.  and thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Few points you can verify

1. Make sure you are using Eclipse JEE version
2. Your tomcat and Eclipse should be using JDK 8 and above, and have the same JAVA_HOME path reference.
3. Also, stop all the tomcat instance, if you are running outside.
4. Try changing the default the tomcat ports, mainly HTTP, startup and shutdown port

Comment: the problem was solved by changing to another workspace in eclipse..i have no idea why....but thank you for your anwser anyway